# C++ Inherit several time from same template class, ambiguous on methods without parameter ( same signature )

Tags: c++, templates, multiple-inheritance

I am writing Interface and Invoker class that allows a class to be several type of invoker and several type of interface.

I don't manage to fix ambiguities in compilation when the function have no parameters ( so all versions have same signature ).
I tried to templatize the function so I can specialize when calling, but It still not removing the ambiguities.
I Know there several article here that talk about similar issue, but they are all with a parameter in the method so the signature is different for each specialization which remove the ambiguity.
I wrote a sample project as small as possible to show.
The workaround for the function Invoker::Interfaces is to add a parameter in the function, and they I can call with (IMyInterface*)0 , but this is ugly .
The workaround for the function Invoker::Register, is to static cast the parameter, but with a template it should find automatically the type of the parameter and I shouldn't need that.

Some help would be very grateful. So I could remove those ugly workarounds.
Thanks a lot.
Here the sample code.

template interface base class

```
template <class INVOKER>
class Interface
{
public:
    INVOKER& Invoker() { return *m_invoker; }
private:
    template <typename> friend class Invoker;
    INVOKER* m_invoker;
};
```

template Invoker base class:

```
template <class INTERFACE>
class Invoker
{
public:
    template<class I>
    void    Register(INTERFACE* _interface) { m_interfaces.push_back(_interface); }

    void    Register(INTERFACE* _interface) { m_interfaces.push_back(_interface); }

    std::vector<INTERFACE*> Interfaces() { return m_interfaces; }

    std::vector<INTERFACE*> Interfaces(INTERFACE*) { return m_interfaces; }

    template<class I>
    std::vector<INTERFACE*> Interfaces() { return m_interfaces; }

private:
    std::vector<INTERFACE*> m_interfaces;
};
```

A short as possible of multi inheritance usage:

```
class DogLover;
class InterfaceDog : public Interface<DogLover>
{
public:
    virtual bool AskIfGoodBoy() = 0;
};

class CatLover;
class InterfaceCat : public Interface<CatLover>
{
public:
    virtual void    Pet() = 0;
};

class DogLover : public Invoker<InterfaceDog> {};
class CatLover : public Invoker<InterfaceCat> {};

class PetLover
    : public DogLover
    , public CatLover
{
public:
    using DogLover::Register;
    using DogLover::Interfaces;

    using CatLover::Register;
    using CatLover::Interfaces;

    int Size() { return m_size; }

    void DoStuff()
    {
        for (InterfaceDog* interface : Interfaces((InterfaceDog*)0))
        {
            interface->AskIfGoodBoy();
        }
        /*
        for (InterfaceCat* interface : Interfaces<InterfaceCat>()) << ambigous
        {
            interface->Pet();
        }*/
    }
private:
    int m_size = 0;
};

class PetOwner
    : public InterfaceCat
    , public InterfaceDog
{
    //using InterfaceDog::Invoker;
    //using InterfaceCat::Invoker;

    void Pet() override     { /*        Invoker().Size(); */}
    bool AskIfGoodBoy() override { return true; }
};
```

Main :

```
int main()
{
    PetLover    petLover;
    PetOwner    petOwner;

    //petLover.Register<DogLover>(&petOwner); // << ambigous
    //petLover.Register<CatLover>(&petOwner); // << ambigous

    petLover.Register(static_cast<InterfaceDog*>(&petOwner));
    petLover.Register(static_cast<InterfaceCat*>(&petOwner));
}
```

Comment: using visual studio 2022 C++20, but I tried C++14 it's also compiling, what line you have this error?

Comment: Ha I see when you uncomment, I bad copy paste sorry

 petLover.Register<DogLover>(&petOwner); // << ambigous
 petLover.Register<CatLover>(&petOwner); // << ambigous

But you have then to comment the workaround ( the 2 lines after ) and the non template declaration in the class 

template <class INTERFACE>
class Invoker
{
public:
// void Register(INTERFACE* _interface) { m_interfaces.push_back(_interface); }

Comment: `for (InterfaceDog* interface : DogLover::Interfaces())`?

Comment: the idea is to use a template with Interfaces() and use a specialization, passing another parameter is just another wokaround I don't want

Comment: `for (InterfaceDog* interface : DogLover::Interfaces())` , how I forgot to try that, this one compiles and I just traced the code , it works.
Thanks, tomorrow I will try this solution on the real project. Thanks.

22:15 here, so I will add a solution to the quesiton tmr once I tested in my main project.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @fabian (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991525/fabian)

I forgot the obvious simplest solution :) which it to specify the class which from you want to call the method like this
Interface:

```
for (InterfaceCat* interface : CatLover::Interfaces())
{
    interface->Pet();
}
```

Register:

```
petLover.DogLover::Register(&petOwner);
petLover.CatLover::Register(&petOwner);
```

Invoker:

```
class PetOwner
    : public InterfaceCat
    , public InterfaceDog
{
    void Pet() override
    {
        InterfaceDog::Invoker().Size();
    }
```